# How can I fix "Can't resolve reference" error when referencing an $id in the same document?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I want to validate a JSON against a JSON schema with Ajv in JavaScript. I get the error:

throw new it.MissingRefError(it.baseId, $schema, $message);
        ^
Error: can't resolve reference #/definitions/requestGraph from id requestGetGraphs

When removing reference to other schema:
        { "$ref" : "#/definitions/requestGraph" }
the error disappears.

JavaScript-code:

```
ajv.addSchema(require('./json-schema/graph-response'), 'graph-response.json');
ajv.validate('requestGetGraphs', `{"type" : "requestGetGraphs", "space" : "config", "v" : 1.1, "id" : "dsaf" }`);
```

graph-request.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id" : "graph-requests.json",
  "definitions": {
    "requestGraph" : {
      "$id" : "#/definitions/requestGraph",
      "allOf" : [
        { "$ref" : "call.json/#/definitions/request" },
        {
          "properties": {
            "space": {
              "$id" : "#requestGraph/properties/space",
              "type": "string",
              "const": "config"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "requestGetGraphs" : {
      "$id" : "requestGetGraphs",
      "type" : "object",
      "allOf" : [
        {
          "properties": {
            "action": {
              "$id" : "#requestGetGraphs/properties/action",
              "type": "string",
              "const": "requestGetGraphs"
            }
          }
        },
        { "$ref" : "#/definitions/requestGraph" }
      ]

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with URI resolution.
Check https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-8.2.2

> When an "$id" sets the base URI, the object containing that "$id" and
> all of its subschemas can be identified by using a JSON Pointer
> fragment starting from that location.  This is true even of
> subschemas that further change the base URI.  Therefore, a single
> subschema may be accessible by multiple URIs, each consisting of base
> URI declared in the subschema or a parent, along with a JSON Pointer
> fragment identifying the path from the schema object that declares
> the base to the subschema being identified.  Examples of this are
> shown in section 8.2.4.

Because you specified `requestGetGraphs` without a hash in front, it resolves as if a new schema (because it's not a fragment). Prefixing your $id with a hash signifies it's a fragment identifier, and URI resolution happens accordingly.

You probably also meant to nest `requestGetGraphs` inside `properties`, right?

Comment: The reference is inside the same file. I can also read the documentation for ajv. But what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I'll take another look.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. I had to set the main root to "$id" : "http://example.com/graph-requests.json#" and put a hash in front of the id on requestGetGraphs. Then I had to validate with ref: graph-requests.json#/requestGetGraphs. Could you delete your first answere? I already got that theory, and the post will be easier to read for others.

Comment: Super! I'll remove my first answer and edit your question title to better reflect the question.

Comment: You didn't need to set a full root $id, but it's also good practice.

Answer (score 48):

If you are here for the `@typescript-eslint` related build error `can't resolve reference #/definitions/directiveConfigSchema from id #` which appeared out of blue yesterday, just downgrade "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" to version "5.33.0". If you don't have it in your package.json just add it (without the ^ in version). Remove your yarn.lock, package-lock.json and node_modules and rebuild.

More information at https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/5525

Comment: I commented to this thread because it was the first result when you google the error.

Comment: Seems the latest version needs a fix. Just upvoted your answer.

Comment: Confirm that this fix works

Comment: Update to `v5.35.1` to consume the `@typescript-eslint` package fix